# Matrix - Vector value matching

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix, indexing

In my current project, I need to find values inside of an matrix that match with individual vector values. This is an example of the process; the main program has me using lat and lon values. But I create a 20x20 matrix and then a 20x1 array of randomly placed values. 
When i do the for loop, each iteration of the Leroy vector is subtracted from every value in matrix. The first min function should return the smallest value from each column and its correspoding index. The second min function should return the smallest overall value from the first min function. and which index had the smallest value. 
My concern is that im not sure which integer inside the matrix returned the smallest value. Is there a way I can use the indexes or something to figure that out?

```
Matrix = magic(20);
Leroy = randi(20,20,1);
for i = 1:length(Leroy)
    [Jenkins, J] = min(min(Leroy(i) - Matrix);
end
```

Comment: Are you by chance missing an `abs` call? Currently, each loop iteration will find the same minimum, you can replace the loop and just look for the location of the minimum in `-Matrix`, or the maximum in `Matrix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Matrix = magic(20);
Leroy = randi(20,20,1);
for i = 1:length(Leroy)
   [Jenkins, J] = min((Leroy(i) - Matrix).^2);
end
```

Using this will help get a match between two values in two arrays or a match between array values and matrix values

Answer (score 0):

As Cris Luego pointed in his comment, your for loop is not required since

```
Leroy(i) - Matrix
```

translates to something like

```
  5 - [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
```

However, your problem to get the index of the minimum in `-Matrix` can be solved by using `min(-Matrix(:))`:

```
[minimum, minidx] = min(-Matrix(:));
```

However, you will get the linear index. If you need the index for row and column, use

```
  [colidx,rowidx] = ind2sub(size(Matrix), minidx);
```

Comment: But how would you find the matching values without a loop? I need to find matching values between a matrix and an array, not just minimum values in each. I can't use ismember because my real matrix and array won't have the exact matching values every single time

Comment: It seems that I misunderstood your question. What are you looking for? Could you please update your question?! Maybe provide the expected result for your example data.

Comment: Ive actually figured out my issue, I just needed to use a single value in an array to find the closest value in a matrix.

Comment: In that case, provide your solution as an answer allow future readers to see the answer, too.